# Animating position of a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a container div of other divs and I am trying to animate container divs position. Normally I can achieve this animating thing but I got a problem now. I am trying to animate this div to the center of the screen because there will be some other content( which I want to hide with the help of container div) behind the container div when it is animated to the center, and if it is not fixed at the center, the contents (which are behind the container div) becomes visible from left and/or right of the container.

when I set the container divs position as;

**CSS:**

```
#cont{ position:absolute; right: auto; left: auto; top: 130px;}
```

Container div appears at center and doesn't move when browser zoomed. This is the position that I want to have after animation.

Then I set the divs first position and the javascript animation like this;

**CSS:**

```
#cont{ position:absolute; right:20px; left: auto; top: 130px;}
```

This css works for me. Container's initial position is just perfect for me.

**JS:**

```
$('.open').on('click', function(){
        $('#cont').animate({"right":"auto"},1000)});
```

But when I click on the '.open' element. Nothing happens.

Normally the JS codes works because I tried to change positions like that:

setting initial position in css like `right:auto;` and setting in JS like `"right":"20px"`

*This is the fiddle that I have problem, not animating position:*

http://jsfiddle.net/ctarimli/B9h2w/3/

*This is the fiddle which I tried reverse (I set initial "right" and "left" as `auto;` and then changed in JS)*

http://jsfiddle.net/ctarimli/B9h2w/5/

So, why the div is not animating the position in the first fiddle?

Comment: You can't animate to an `auto` value - how should the JS animate to it? Suppose you start from `20px`, what values should it use to interpolate? `21..22..23..` or `19..18..17..` (it can't determine what the "target" value should be)

Comment: @MichaelRose soo is there any other way to animate an element to the center from other position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't animate to an `auto` value - how should the JS animate to it? Suppose you start from `20px`, what values should it use to interpolate? `21..22..23..` or `19..18..17..` (it can't determine what the "target" value should be)

As you stated in your comment, you want it to be centered afterwards. Try giving the `#cont` a fixed width (like `width: 150px;`). Then animate to a right position of 50% (`right: 50%`) and correct the margin with an appropriate `margin-right: -75px;` like so:

```
$('.open').on('click', function() {
    $('#cont').animate({
        "right":"50%",
        "marginRight":"-75px"
    }, 1000)
});
```

See Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B9h2w/17/

Comment: After a zoom like +300% it fails but this is a good result I guess. So, yes this worked for me.